# How to display parents category and child category separately for a specific post?

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I am trying to list the categories of a post in this format: `<Parent Category> -- <Child Category>`. Is there a way to manipulate `the_category()` function to do that, or is there any other way I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should find an immediate parent for you.

```
// get the current category ID
$category_id = get_the_category(get_the_ID());

// get the current category object
$child = get_category($category_id[0]->term_id);

// get it's parent object
$parent = get_category($child->parent);

var_dump($parent->name . ' - ' . $child->name);
```

The same but in a Wordpress loop:

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post'
];
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        // get the current category ID
        $category_id = get_the_category(get_the_ID());

        // get the current category object
        $child = get_category($category_id[0]->term_id);

        // get it's parent object
        $parent = get_category($child->parent);

        dump(get_the_title() . ': ' . $parent->name . ' - ' . $child->name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, can't get it to work. This is what it outputs inside the div
`<li class="parent-cat">
         2<pre class="xdebug-var-dump" dir="ltr"><small>/Users/sadman/Sites/rice/wp-content/themes/rice/template-parts/slider.php:36:</small><small>string</small> <font color="#cc0000">'Current Affairs - '</font> <i>(length=18)</i>
</pre>         
        </li>`

Comment: I think I updated the code above as you were writing your comment. Is the revised code any better? I am manually passing in an ID instead of get_the_ID(), and get the output as expected. Could you test it manually perhaps?

Comment: Tried the updated one too, but still shows the same error.

Comment: Are you using a foreach or the wordpress loop to build that list? If it's a foreach, you may need to use setup_postdata() before calling get_the_ID.

Comment: No I am using a standard WP_Query loop using a few arguments - no foreach.

Comment: I've just tried it with the following and have it working on a local install. Could you share any more of your surrounding code?
// edit: I've added the code to the answer for readability.

Comment: Sure, here is my loop: https://pastebin.com/64AqQ5Ja
I am trying to replace the_category with your code, but it gives the error that I pasted before.

Comment: How about like this? https://pastebin.com/RyuDcs0E my example has a few less args to make it work on my fresh install, but you should be able to spot the integration in the middle.